# Find the last two digits of the given number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Problem:

> Find the last $2$ digits of $7^{2008}$.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve this problem. I know that for the last digit, we have to apply the concept of cyclicity, but I'm not aware of how to extend this to the last $2$ digits. I would be truly grateful for any help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the first few exponents modulo 100.

Comment: How can a question about the last two digits of $7^{2008}$ be a duplicate of a question about the last two digits of $7^{81}$??? At best, they would have similar answers. This community is developing a rather bad habit of closing down questions!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just a clarification to Subhadeep's answer in case it is confusing.

Let us first build a small table with everything larger than 100 in parentheses:
$$\begin{array}{lr}7^0 = &1\\
7^1 =& 7\\
7^2 =& 49\\
7^3 =& (3)43\\
7^4 =& (24)01\\
\end{array}$$

So we see that after 4 we get "back" to 1. This means $7^{4k}$ will end in 01 for all $k$. So if we can calculate the exponent modulo 4 we can see which of 01,07,49,43 it will be.

As the exponent 2008 is divisible by 4 it must be "01".

Comment: I think this is what the OP was looking for, more than just a solution. So +1

Answer (score 11):

$$7^4\equiv 01\pmod {100}\\\implies (7^4)^{502}\equiv (01)^{502}\pmod {100}\\\implies 7^{2008}\equiv 01\pmod {100} $$.

Hence the last two digits are $01$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** $~7^{2008}=49^{1004}=(50-1)^{1004}.~$ Now expand using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), and notice that all terms except for the first two are multiples of $50^2$, and therefore of $100$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $7$ and $100$ are coprime with respect to each other, you can use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem):

- $7^{\phi(100)}\equiv1\pmod{100}$
- $\phi(100)=\phi(2^2\cdot5^2)=2\cdot4\cdot5=40$
- $7^{40}\equiv1\pmod{100}$
- $7^{2008}=7^{40\cdot50+8}=(7^{40})^{50}\cdot7^8$
- $(7^{40})^{50}\cdot7^8\equiv1^{50}\cdot7^8\equiv1\cdot5764801\equiv5764801\equiv01\pmod{100}$

Comment: +1,but, it is a problem of simple application of congruence theory, here $\phi$-function is not inevitably needed. Moreover, the $7^8$ is looking cumbersome, and much toilsome to compute, where in the simpler approach I did,calculating $7^4$ will suffice.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: Thank you. I showed a way which did not require you to start by going around searching for a value of $n$ such that $7^n\equiv1\pmod{100}$. In the general case, it might be a lot harder than checking only the first few exponents. Of course, in this specific case, I do agree that towards the end of the method, once you calculate $7^8$, you realize that you've got yourself such value of $n$ with which you could do the all thing a lot more simple, as $7^{2008}=(7^8)^{251}$.

Comment: There's a quote by CAR Hoare that reads "There are two ways of constructing a software design: One way is to make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies, and the other way is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious deficiencies." I think that applies *a little bit* here.

Comment: @SpamIAm: Thanks for pointing that out, I will fix in a minute. I got the right answer since $2008\bmod{16}=2008\bmod{40}=8$, so there's little surprise in that. Thanks.

Comment: @SpamIAm: BTW, my mistake wasn't a gross misunderstanding of $\phi$ as you might have implied, but a simple miscalculation of $(2-1)\cdot(2-1)\cdot(5-1)\cdot(5-1)=16$ instead of $40$.

Comment: @SpamIAm: I meant to say that $100=2\cdot2\cdot5\cdot5\implies\phi(100)=\phi(2\cdot2\cdot5\cdot5)=(2-1)\cdot(2-1)\cdot(5-1)\cdot(5-1)$, and that my only mistake was the calculation of $(2-1)\cdot(2-1)\cdot(5-1)\cdot(5-1)$, not the interpretation of $\phi(100)$.

Comment: @SpamIAm: Oh, S#$%t, you are right. I will delete this answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Much better! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @SpamIAm: Haha, thanks. Though I generally prefer to delete an answer rather than fixing it over and over, I guess that the other bullets (the ones which I didn't need to fix) are worth something for the readers. Thanks...

Comment: @SpamIAm: BTW, it was a good "$\phi$" lesson, I guess I kinda forgot how to compute it and just took out what I had in my sleeve.

Answer (score 3):

Start by listing some cases of $7^n \mod 100:$
$$7^0=\color{red}{01}$$
$$7^1=\color{red}{07}$$
$$7^2=\color{red}{49}$$
$$7^3=3\color{red}{43}$$
$$7^4=24\color{red}{01}$$
$$7^5=168\color{red}{07}$$
$$7^6=1176\color{red}{49}$$
$$7^7=8235\color{red}{43}$$
$$7^8=57648\color{red}{01}$$
$$7^9=403536\color{red}{07}$$
$$7^{10}=2824752\color{red}{49}$$
$$7^{11}=19773267\color{red}{43}$$
$$7^{12}=138412872\color{red}{01}$$
$$\dots$$

Do you see the pattern?